# How can I force iPhone’s Safari to use media="handheld"?

Tags: iphone, html, css, xhtml, mobile-website

Is there a way to force to iPhone’s Safari to use `media="handheld"` in place of `media="screen"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Safari intentionally disregards media=handheld, as such stylesheets were typically tailored to pre-iPhone handhelds with much lower capabilities, and would therefore result in a poor low-quality version of the page.

However, you can direct Safari to use specific stylesheets using [conditional css](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW2).