# Can I force iOS Safari to recognize handheld media queries?

Tags: ios, css, safari, media-queries

Plain and simple. How can I force iOS Safari to recognize this?

```
BUTTON {
    padding: 0 0.5em; /* To conserve screen space on point-and-click interfaces */
}

@media handheld {
    BUTTON {
        padding: 1em 2em; /* So fingers can more easily touch it */
    }
}
```

I've already read [How can I force iPhone’s Safari to use media="handheld"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123091/how-can-i-force-iphones-safari-to-use-media-handheld), but that was asked over 3 years ago. In today's age of HTML5- and CSS3-compliance and where standards are embraced so easily, I'm hoping Apple put something in iOS Safari to be able to allow handeld media queries to be honored on the iPhone's now-relatively-tiny screen.

I tried using exact values, such as `screen and (max-width: 5in)`, but apparently it thinks its screen is wider than 5 inches.

Comment: What does HTML5/CSS3 compliance have to do with the simple fact that Mobile Safari is too advanced to be simply considered a "handheld" browser as implied by that answer? If anything, the more advanced it is, the more reason it has to stay further away from that media type.

Comment: I think you're confused. It's not that I doubt that Safari is advanced, it's that I want a smooth, easy-to-use experience for my end users. To do this, I want my webpages to work like their apps do, allowing larger buttons, non-hover interaction, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this target a particular device width.

```
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: YourDeviceWidth){

       //Styles for this device width here.
    }
```

Or you could use device-aspect-ratio for Iphone+Ipad:

iPhone < 5:

```
        @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {
        }
```

iPhone 5:

```
        @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {
        }
```

iPad:

```
        @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {
        }
```